# Is it possible to calculate how much memory ubuntu will need to boot?

Tags: boot, kernel, ram

Upgrading ubuntu 16.04 (server, not gui) to 4.4.0-194 kernel resulted in out of memory errors on a number of my servers, they'd been minimal purpose-built customized ubuntu vm's that had worked well for the past 4 years on 256 MB (which admittedly is less than the installation guide says, but is a nice round number that vmware appreciates). Obviously I'm working on replacing them, but in the meantime I need to keep them patched.

I've found several threads about using slaptop and lsmod to show how much memory the kernel *is* using, but is there any way to know, other than rebooting and being disappointed, to find out how much ram the kernel is *going* to use?  I must be on the cusp of bootability and have something random in my build process because only about 1-3% of my fleet is experiencing this problem.

Comment: I don't know about the exact amount but it depends on whether you want to use the GUI (~1GB is required), or simply boot to the CLI (even < 200 mb memory would be enough for booting).

Comment: @arch it's weird, we're using 256MB and the cli, it had been working just fine until now.  I can't see where all the RAM is going, slabtop, lsmod, and the size of the kernel files in /boot don't add up to anywhere near 256 MB (maybe 100MB).  So I must be missing something

Comment: Run `htop` to see which process is taking most memory (you may have to install it first with `sudo apt-get install htop`)

Comment: If the RAM usage is only temporary then it will be hard to find from within the VM. I would take advantage of the virtualization environment and monitor the RAM usage from outside of the VM. May be reduce the CPU MHz to slow everything down. Then boot the machine and monitor RAM usage, pause the machine when RAM usage is at maximum before VM panics and write RAM content to file for analyzing it.